# Not able to Delete components Adobe AEM 6.5

Tags: java, aem, aem-6

Not able to Delete components Adobe AEM 6.5 TOUCHUI mode

Checked network logs, no errors, cq-authoring-mode = TOUCHUI

How to replicate problem.

On page in author, click on component, context menu appears on top of component, click delete icon, delete dialog box appears to confirm or cancel, click to confirm Delete.

Component vanishes, then refresh page, component re-appears.

checked network log and error log, no errors showing

On page in author, click on component, context menu appears on top of component, click delete icon, delete dialog box appears to confirm or cancel, click to confirm Delete.

Component vanishes, then refresh page, component re-appears.

checked network log and error log, no errors showing

Comment: Does this happen to you in a vanilla instance? If you reinstall, does it works before you deploy your project?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check that if you have neccassary permisions or is there any other restrictions on the components. Also you can try to clear browser caches or use a different browser, it seems odd if there is no errors on log. In addition is there another script running on the page, maybe it might be interfering

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes am logged in as admin and I have cleared all cache and tried different browsers as well, the issue is still persisting. Additionally, this is affecting all pages for all sites.

Comment: If it is affecting all pages for all sites, problem could be more deeper, maybe recent updates on Adobe AEM or another system update or program could be cause it. I would do clean reinstall and if problem persist, try on another computer, if there wont be a problem on other computers, i would check recent changes in system softwares etc. Sorry i couldnt help further, its beyond my knowledge=)